# How to find out the number of times group was matched in Python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

Metacharacter `+`: one or more occurrences. What is the general method to get the number of this occurrences?

For example:

```
import re

x = re.finditer(r'0(10)+(20)+', '0001010202020000')
for i in iter(x):
  print(i) # <re.Match object; span=(2, 13), match='01010202020'>
```

I want to get: `[('01', 2), ('02', 3)]` due to `(10)+` and `(20)+` in regex.

Comment: Do you mean `[('10', 2), ('20', 3)]`  as you are matching repetitions of 10 and 20?

Comment: yes, [('10', 2), ('20', 3)] due to repetitions of 10 and 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do this is to enclose each repeating capture group inside another group, then you can divide the length of the outer match by the length of the inner match to determine how many times each inner group matched. For example:

```py
import re

m = re.search(r'0((10)+)((20)+)', '0001010202020000')
num_grps = len(m.groups())
for i in range(1, num_grps+1,2):
    outer = m.end(i) - m.start(i)
    inner = m.end(i+1) - m.start(i+1)
    print((m.group(i+1), outer//inner))
```

Output:

```py
('10', 2)
('20', 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `re`, but as an alternative using `regex` with the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you could use the same pattern and make use counting the `captures()` which gives a list of all the captures of a group.

```
import regex

x = regex.search(r'0(10)+(20)+', '0001010202020000')
res = []
for i, val in enumerate(x.groups(), 1):
    res.append((val, len(x.captures(i))))

print(res)
```

Output

```
[('10', 2), ('20', 3)]
```

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##JYvRCoMwDEXf@xV5a8qKVPc22JcMH4rLtKBtiHW4r@/Cdi6ES5LDn7qUfG0tbVykgtBMpzEn3P@12ynKtKDYgH1wFxx0WA82hNBrhl8U64zQrtpjNK8ikDy84wopA@VjI4mV8OxmKQfv6Dz07mZAUamLzJSfiCp4WCnr4xS5HnrD5BRjWFKuqAvX2hc)

Comment: Yet another handy feature of `regex`. btw, you can pass `1` as the second parameter to `enumerate` (i.e. `enumerate(x.groups(), 1)`) to get it to start counting from 1 instead of 0 and save yourself the `+1` on `i`.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the tip, learning something new everyday :-)

Comment: Seemed only fair since I learned about `.captures` from you :) I must spend some more time with pypi regex...

Answer (score -1):

This is not supported by regular expression engine, you would have to do it yourself. In this case you can capture both the repeated string and the result of the repetition, then count the repetitions yourself.

```
matches = re.finditer(r'0((10)+)((20)+)', '0001010202020000')
for match in matches:
    item = [(pattern, len(instance) // len(pattern))
            for instance, pattern in zip(*[iter(match.groups())]*2)]
    print(item)
```

Note that it won't work on a non-fixed subpatterns. In this case, you would have to run `findall` (or `finditer`) on the match group itself and count.